# Caching compile layers of a Docker container

Tags: c++, docker, build, continuous-integration

I am dockerizing the build process of some C++ binaries. But not every build will necessarily involve changes to the source code of all of them.

So, I only want to build binaries that have new, unique source code associated to them. Binaries that have been previously built should just use the existing file system layer.

In my dockerfile is the following. As is, this will only ever build the binaries once, and never acknowledge that the source code has changed. How can I make Docker aware of relevant source code changes?

```
RUN pushd "gnome" && rm -Rf workers && mkdir -p workers && ./scripts/buildCaptureTeamcity.sh && popd
RUN pushd "gnome" && rm -Rf workers && mkdir -p workers && ./scripts/buildOswaldTeamcity.sh && popd
RUN pushd "gnome" && rm -Rf workers && mkdir -p workers && ./scripts/buildRecorderTeamcity.sh && popd
RUN pushd "gnome" && rm -Rf workers && mkdir -p workers && ./scripts/buildSamTeamcity.sh && popd
RUN pushd "gnome" && rm -Rf workers && mkdir -p workers && ./scripts/buildTransmitTeamcity.sh && popd
```

I was vaguely thinking that I could take a SHA of the source code directory and prepend that to each command in the form of an ARG. Then each SHA of the source code would be unique and get its own filesystem layer and not be recompiled unless necessary. Like so

```
  docker build -t code/code:teamcity_$TEAMCITY_BUILD_ID --build-arg buildtime_variable=$(shasum -a256 gnome/oswald/src/*) .

#Dockerfile
ARG buildtime_variable
RUN _=${buildtime_variable} pushd "gnome" && rm -Rf workers && mkdir -p workers && ./scripts/buildOswaldTeamcity.sh && popd
```

Does that make sense? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Don't use a Dockerfile; those are for building Docker containers, not for building other things inside Docker containers.

Comment: The code will be ran in production in a docker container on kubernetes

Comment: I am trying to make my build process efficient in both time, and space consumed